# Close a connection after an error is thrown

Tags: python, mysql

I have a python tornado module running through a server using docker.

I have a python file that communicates with my java script project using web sockets. This python file then communicates with a second python file that communicates with my SQL server.

The problem is that if an error is returned from the SQL server due to a bad query, the connection to the connection pool hangs, and quickly enough the pool becomes full, breaking the functionality of the JS project

I've looked at some of guides and SO problems, but can't find one that addresses this issue

My common function in my server.py file is as follows:

```py
    def log_training(self, message_data):
        message_type = "training_failed"

        try:
            database_manager.log("training", message_data)
            message_type = "training_successful"
        except: 
            tb = traceback.format_exc()
            print("Traceback | Training Log\t| ", "\t\t", "| Error: ", tb)

        self.send_message(message_type, "")
```

and the database_manager.log() function is:

```py
    def log(self, table_name, my_dict):
        connector = self.cnxpool.get_connection() 
        cursor = connector.cursor(buffered=True, dictionary=True) 

        columns = ', '.join(my_dict.keys())
        values = ", ".join(["%s"] * len(my_dict))

        query = """INSERT INTO {table} ({columns}) VALUES ({values});""".format(table=table_name, columns=columns, values=values)
        print("SQL\t\t| Query: " , query)
        print("SQL\t\t| Columns: ", columns)
        print("SQL\t\t| Values: ", my_dict.values())

        cursor.execute(query, list(my_dict.values()))

        connector.commit()
        cursor.close()
        connector.close()
```

So, if the database_manager.log() return an exception, connector.close() is never called

Answer (score 1):

Why not add another try: to your database_manager.log()

```
try:
     cursor.execute(query, list(my_dict.values()))
except Exception,e:
    print "Error"

else:
    connector.commit()
finally:
    cursor.close()
    connector.close()
```

Handle the error better but this is an outline of what you could do.

Comment: This is exactly the solution I tried after posting the question, it's midnight in Ireland right now, so I'll do some extensive testing with live users tomorrow to test the solution